# How to hide url in Chrome custom tab android

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I have implemented new **Chrome Custom Tab** in android, I am using the following code to open

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://akash.plobal.com/ploicy");
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();                   
intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(Color.BLACK);
intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true);
intentBuilder.build().launchUrl(getActivity(), uri);
```

I need to hide url below the title in toolbar

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you control both the content and the application, you can use [Trusted Web Activities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) to completely remove the URL bar. You'll need to implement [Digital Asset Links](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links) to validate the ownership of both.

If you don't own the content, it is not possible to hide the URL below the title. The URLs needs to visible to the user, so that they can know in which site they are. By removing this from the UI, a malicious site could mimic the UI of another one, and this could potentially create a security issue for users.

Comment: Indeed, this is by design, and an important part of the security model of custom tabs. If you do not need access to the user's browser state (i.e. cookies, etc. that have already been set in their browser) you can use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display the contents of this page without any decoration.

Comment: is there any way to hide the close button?

Comment: How can we change the title of the tab in xamarin.android?

Comment: Good answer, but still we need a solution. Unfortunately, the Webview uses bad/outofdate/old engine that fails to display modern web-pages correctly, thus we need a solution to have the ability to display any web-page correctly, like the superb chrome engine. 
Shortly - So, is there any other solution to the problem ?

Comment: Trusted Web Activities are now an option, if you own both the application and the content being opened. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot hide the url alone. You can only get rid of the whole title bar, that too when the user scroll the view. To achieve this,use

> intentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding();

Comment: intentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding(); this will hide whole toolbar while user scroll down the page

Answer (score -7):

You can try `setShowTitle(false)` of your custom tab.