# Hide the location bar in Chrome Custom Tabs in MAUI

Tags: android, maui, chrome-custom-tabs

So that I don't ask the wrong question, my end goal is to build a PWA that is accessible from Android 5.x and up now and iOS later in the year. The main problem with this is Classic Bluetooth is not yet stable/standardized enough for the web.

My next plan was to build a "native" app (in .NET MAUI so that I can reuse parts in iOS) using a WebView for displaying the PWA and calling back to the native app for Bluetooth. The problem here is the WebView version on the devices I have to support doesn't support PWAs, service workers, etc. (upgrading the hundred or so hardware devices is not possible, upgrading the OS is not possible, and it's pre-Android-8 so upgrading WebView is not possible without a new ROM).

Finally I've tried installing Chrome via device management and using "[Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/)" from MAUI. The simplest implementation works:

```
// Browser is <IBrowser>Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Browser.Default
await Browser.OpenAsync(
    "https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/",
    BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

and the tab is displayed "in" my app, however the location bar is shown within the tab:
[image: Android screenshot showing location bar in Chrome Custom Tab]

## Which brings me to the question:

*How do I use a Chrome Custom Tab from MAUI but hide the location bar?* Is this even possible?

There's little to no documentation on this for MAUI. I've tried looking through the MAUI source, but all I can see are some options:

```
await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/", new BrowserLaunchOptions
{
    LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred, // open inside the MAUI app, i.e. Custom Tab
    TitleMode = BrowserTitleMode.Hide, // doesn't seem to have any effect
    Flags = BrowserLaunchFlags.LaunchAdjacent // the only Android flag
});
```

The LaunchAdjacent flag just opens "up" instead of sideways. The other flags are for iOS, [detailed here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/cdf43dafaf2dd30ec8732adcb4df855465e9623f/src/Essentials/docs/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials/BrowserLaunchFlags.xml). The TitleMode doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Reading about Chrome Custom Tabs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157921/1089267), it appears it's not possible, unless I own the destination URL and setup a [Trusted Web Activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/). Hosting a web app combined with a native app for Bluetooth may be the only way to go if I can't use a WebView.